# Eclipse 'Debug View'

Tags: eclipse, debug

So this might be a silly question,  but I'm seeing a 'debug output' view in my eclipse workspace, and I haven't got the foggiest idea what it's for.  I'm presuming it's useful - but Googling hasn't found me a explanation, could someone point me in the direction of a definition/tutorial?

[image]

Comment: So are you concerned about one specific view called "debug output" or are you having troubles understanding the general notion of "debugging?"

Comment: Maybe you could add a screenshot so it's clear which view you are talking about.

Comment: Added screenshot - apologies, yes I'm happy with debugging as a general concept and occasional use, on one such occasional use I thought - 'I wonder what that is?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Eclipse mainly for Java development and was also confused about the `Debug Output` view since I haven't noticed it before. I used `Plugin Spy` and figured out that it is contributed from the `org.eclipse.php.debug.ui` bundle. Apparently it is used for php development and if you use a different language - just close it :)